# 'Could not load file or assembly' error while adding WCF service reference to client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I am trying to create a WCF service client by adding a service reference of a WCF service that uses net.tcp binding. But I am getting following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'CoreService-PP-DELL' or one
>   of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.

Following is my WCF server configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="CoreService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="beh1">
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:2205/Service1.svc"/>
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
        <endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.IAccountService"/>
       <endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.ICategoryService"/>
         <endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.ICommonService"/>
         <endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.IFollowerService"/>
         <endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.IInterestService"/>
<endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.IInviteService"/>

  <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexTcpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
</services>
<bindings>
<netTcpBinding>
<binding name="ultra"
     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
     maxBufferSize="2147483647"
     maxConnections="2147483647"
     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
     portSharingEnabled="false"
     transactionFlow="false"
     listenBacklog="2147483647"
     sendTimeout="00:01:00">
<security mode="None">
<message clientCredentialType="None"/>
<transport protectionLevel="None" clientCredentialType="None"/>
</security>
<reliableSession enabled="false"/>
</binding>
</netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="beh1">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="65536" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with WCF. Search this site for the error you get: _"The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster actually it's not able to find the assembly of this WCF service. I rebuilded it but its not working.

Comment: It doesn't matter what's in the assembly, the assembly manifest doesn't match.

Comment: thanks @CodeCaster I solved it. I removed everything from the built folder and rebuilt it. But I am facing another problem. Here is the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146035/unable-to-add-service-client-for-a-net-tcp-wcf-service

Answer (score 1):

You can try **Fusion log viewer** - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e74a18c4(v=vs.100).aspx

to discover lost dependencies (assemblies) of CoreService-PP-DELL