# Unable to add service client for a net.tcp WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, tcp

I am trying to add a client for a WCF service that is net.tcp based. When I use "Add Service Reference" and provide this URL:**net.tcp://localhost/service1.svc**, it gives following error.

> The URI prefix is not recognized. Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost/service1.svc'. Could not
>   connect to net.tcp://localhost/service1.svc. The connection attempt
>   lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0051147. TCP error code 10061: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 127.0.0.1:808.  No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:808 If the service is defined in
>   the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

I checked Windows Components for WCF non-http services, but they are already installed. This is the snap:

[image: Enabling non-http protocols for WCF services]

As you can see they are installed for .NET 3.5.1 and my service is built in .NET 4.5. Is this the problem? And how should I solve it? Because there is no option for .NET 4.5 in Windows Components List.

Following is the configuration of my WCF service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="CoreService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="beh1">
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/Service1.svc"/>
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
        <endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.IAccountService"/>
       <endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.ICategoryService"/>
         <endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.ICommonService"/>
         <endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.IFollowerService"/>
         <endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.IInterestService"/>
<endpoint
     binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="ultra"
     contract="CoreService.IInviteService"/>

  <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexTcpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
</services>
<bindings>
<netTcpBinding>
<binding name="ultra"
     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
     maxBufferSize="2147483647"
     maxConnections="2147483647"
     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
     portSharingEnabled="false"
     transactionFlow="false"
     listenBacklog="2147483647"
     sendTimeout="00:01:00">
<security mode="None">
<message clientCredentialType="None"/>
<transport protectionLevel="None" clientCredentialType="None"/>
</security>
<reliableSession enabled="false"/>
</binding>
</netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="beh1">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="65536" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem an incompatibility issue between the WCF HTTP or Non-HTTP Activation features and your service.

According to me, there's a missing or wrong configuration in IIS and that would explain the refused connection. To configure properly IIS with with `net.tcp`, have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms731053%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I cross checked the configuration and only problem was that I didn't added net.tcp to the enabled protocols of the website. But after I added, it showed following error `There is no compatible TransportManager found for URI. . This may be because you have used an absolute address that points outside of the virtual application, or the binding settings of the endpoint do not match those that have been set by other services or endpoints. Note that all bindings for the same protocol should have the same settings in the same application.`

Comment: It's solved now. I removed maxConnection property and it worked. :)